# What is an example of the use of Application.UnprocessedKeyHandler in Apache Pivot?

Tags: apache-pivot

What is an example of the use of `Application.UnprocessedKeyHandler` in Apache Pivot? I've checked Google and the Pivot docs and see no examples, and the Javadoc isn't enlightening. There's a tease of sample code [in the mailing list archives](http://apache-pivot-users.399431.n3.nabble.com/KeyListeners-on-ImageView-td2600622.html), but the code attachment is not available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple, the Javadoc confused me for some reason. Just add the `UnprocessedKeyHandler` interface to whatever class in the project is implementing `org.apache.pivot.wtk.Application`, and then of course implement in that class the methods from the interface.

A start of an example would be to take, say:

`public class HelloWorld implements Application`

And change it to:

`public class HelloWorld implements Application, UnprocessedKeyHandler`

The thread that led to this solution can be found [here](http://apache-pivot-users.399431.n3.nabble.com/What-is-an-example-of-the-use-of-Application-UnprocessedKeyHandler-in-Apache-Pivot-td4022641.html).